# Repeated login failure for 'sa' on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I'm getting about 20 of these every hour on one of our production servers:

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ]

From extended events I can see that half come from `client_app_name .Net SqlClient Data Provider`, the other half come from `client_app_name    Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`

How can I determine the process that is attempting these logons?
The server is not public facing - internal only.
We started getting this error immediately after upgrading from SQL 2014 to SQL2016 SP1.

Comment: Is the server accessible public? The it is just the usual everyday bot scan for weak `sa`. The appname can be faked.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from SQL2014 to SQL2016 several maintenance plans could no longer log in as SA.
I reworked these plans to use a Windows login instead of SA.